# Joomla! Wrong BASE HREF changing HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: http, https, joomla, href

I just moved my Joomla! website from [BradPPresents.com](http://BradPPresents.com) to [BradP.com](http://BradP.com). No Nude, but MAY NOT BE SFW

Everything works properly on unsecured HTTP access;
But as soon as the site changes to HTTPS: the BASE HREF reverts to the OLD url "BradPPresents.com".

I've changed every instance of BradPPresents.com I can find, with no success.

Does anyone know what to do? Feel free to check out the site and experiment at will.

Thank you.
Best,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only place you really need to change is the configuration.php file. There must not remain a single one reference to BradPPresents.com

I have recently moved a Joomla site from one place to another and all it took was to fiddle with the configuration.php file for a while.